# c++ get() doesn't set eof

Tags: c++, c++11

The function `std::get()` normally sets an `eofbit` when at the end of file. Since c++11 `std::unget()` first clears this bit and then proceds to unget last character read.
What bothers me that after I reach eof, `unget()` doesn't seem to work for me, it only clears the bit but doesn't actually unget anything. Any subsequent calls to `get()` don't even set the `eofbit` again.
Is this intentional, did I miss something in the documentation?

gcc version 6.3.1, -std=c++11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    while ( !cin . eof () )
        cout << " " <<  cin . get () << " ";
    cout << "end" << endl;
    cout << cin . eof () << endl;
    cout << (bool)cin . unget () << endl; 
    cout << cin . eof () << endl;
    cout << cin . get () << endl;
    cout << cin . eof () << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

example input `foobar`

example output

```
 102  111  111  98  97  114  10  -1 end
1
0
0
-1
0
```

What really bothers me is not that it puts back the `-1` for eof, but why doesn't it set back `eofbit` after the last `get()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the `eofbit` and `failbit`:

> Reaching the End-of-File sets the eofbit. But note that operations
>   that reach the End-of-File may also set the failbit if this makes them
>   fail (thus setting both eofbit and failbit).

About the `get()`:

> Reads one character and returns it if available. Otherwise, returns
>   Traits::eof() and sets failbit and eofbit.

Unget clears the `eofbit`, but cannot do anything with the `failbit` and thus fails too. Subsequent calls to `get` fail because of `failbit` being set and don't check for next character, because of which they can't set `eofbit`.